Data doesn't persist after reloading?
When I refresh the page (using F5) in the TableListVulnerabilities component, the previously fetched data disappears, and the component appears empty. Why is the data not persisting across page reloads?
This is before reloading
This is after reloading
This is my TableListVulnerabilities.jsx component:
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { DelegationsContext } from '../../context/DelegationsContexts';
import { useInternalVul } from '../../hooks/useInternalVul';
import desconocido from '../../assets/desconocido.png';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faEye, faFileAlt, faClock } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import ModalDetail from './ModalDetailVulDevi';
import styled from '@emotion/styled';
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import PDFReport from './PDFReport'; // Import PDFReport component

const TableListVulnerabilities = () => {
    const { delegation } = useContext(DelegationsContext);
    const { ipVul: vulData, isLoading, isError } = useInternalVul(delegation);
    const { t } = useTranslation();

    const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);
    const [currentDetail, setCurrentDetail] = useState(null);
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [loadingFromStorage, setLoadingFromStorage] = useState(true);
    const handleCloseDialog = () => {
        setOpenModal(false);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        // Check if data is loaded from local storage
        if (loadingFromStorage && !isLoading && !isError && vulData && vulData.scan_internal_ips_vuln) {
            setData(vulData.scan_internal_ips_vuln);
            sessionStorage.setItem('vulData', JSON.stringify(vulData.scan_internal_ips_vuln)); // Store data in sessionStorage
            setLoadingFromStorage(false); // Set indicator to false after loading from storage
        }
    }, [vulData, isLoading, isError, loadingFromStorage]);

    // Retrieve data from sessionStorage on component mount
    useEffect(() => {
        const storedData = sessionStorage.getItem('vulData');
        if (storedData) {
            setData(JSON.parse(storedData));
        }
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Component mounted'); // Log when the component is mounted
    }, []); // Empty dependency array means this effect runs only once, when the component mounts

    const handleDetailClick = (item) => {
        setCurrentDetail(item);
        setOpenModal(true);
    };

    const handleReportClick = (item) => {
        const pdf = new jsPDF();
        const formatDate = (date) => {
            const d = new Date(date);
            const day = d.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
            const month = (d.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
            const year = d.getFullYear().toString().slice(-2);
            return `${month}/${day}/${year}`;
        };

        pdf.setFontSize(16);
        pdf.text('Vulnerability Details', 20, 10);
        pdf.setFontSize(12);
        pdf.text(`ID: ${item._id || 'Unknown'}`, 10, 20);
        pdf.text(`Delegación: ${item.delegation || 'Unknown'}`, 10, 30);
        pdf.text(`IP Interna: ${item.privateip || 'Unknown'}`, 10, 40);
        pdf.text(`MAC: ${item.mac || 'Unknown'}`, 10, 50);
        pdf.text(`Puertos: ${item.ports ? item.ports.join(', ') : 'Unknown'}`, 10, 60);
        pdf.text(`Detectado: ${item.last_detected ? formatDate(item.last_detected) : 'Unknown'}`, 10, 70);
        let yPosition = 90;
        if (item.vulnerabilities) {
            Object.entries(item.vulnerabilities).forEach(([port, { cve }]) => {
                pdf.text(`ID CVE (${port}): ${cve.id || 'Unknown'}`, 10, yPosition);
                yPosition += 10;
                pdf.text(`Puntuación CVSS v3.1: ${cve.metrics.cvssMetricV31[0]?.cvssData.baseScore || 'Unknown'} (${cve.metrics.cvssMetricV31[0]?.cvssData.baseSeverity || 'Unknown'})`, 10, yPosition);
                yPosition += 20;
            });
        }
        const ip = item.privateip || 'Unknown_IP';
        const date = item.last_detected ? formatDate(item.last_detected) : 'Unknown';
        const filename = `${ip}_${date}.pdf`;
        pdf.save(filename);
    };

    if (isLoading) return <div>Loading...</div>;
    if (isError) return <div>Error loading data</div>;

    return (
        <>
            <div className="tableVulnerableDevices flex h-full flex-col overflow-y bg-gradient-to-b from-gray-600 to-gray-900 pt-14">
                <div className="px-4 py-2 sm:px-6 h-screen w-4/5">
                    <div className='content-full font-semibold bg-white rounded-lg text-gray-700 px-30 py-3 grid grid-cols-1 divide-y'>
                        <p className="text-2xl py-5 font-bold text-gray-900">{t('sliderInfoDelegation.vulnerableDivices')}</p>
                        <table className="tvul">
                            <thead className='bg-gray-100'>
                                <tr>
                                    <th className='px-5 py-5'>User</th>
                                    <th>Ip Interna</th>
                                    <th>MAC</th>
                                    <th>Id Vulneravilidad</th>
                                    <th>Puertos</th>
                                    <th>Detectado</th>
                                    <th>Puntuacion Base</th>
                                    <th>Impacto</th>
                                    <th>Severidad</th>
                                    <th>Acciones</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                {vulData?.data?.scan_internal_ips_vuln.map((item) => {
                                    const portKey = Object.keys(item.vulnerabilities)[0];
                                    const vulnerability = item.vulnerabilities[portKey];
                                    const cve = vulnerability.cve;
                                    const metrics = cve.metrics.cvssMetricV31[0].cvssData;
                                    const lastDetected = new Date(item.last_detected);
                                    const formattedDate = lastDetected.toLocaleString();
                                    return (
                                        <tr key={item._id}>
                                            <td><div className='user-cell pt-3 pl-5 '><img src={desconocido} className='user-image w-10 h-10' />{item.user || 'Unknown'}</div></td>
                                            <td>{item.privateip}</td>
                                            <td>{item.mac}</td>
                                            <td>{cve.id}</td>
                                            <td>{item.ports.join(', ')}</td>
                                            <td>{formattedDate}</td>
                                            <td>{metrics.baseScore}</td>
                                            <td>{cve.metrics.cvssMetricV31[0].impactScore}</td>
                                            <td>{metrics.baseSeverity}</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <button onClick={() => handleDetailClick(item)} className='buttonEye text-blue-500' title='Detalle'>
                                                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEye} />
                                                </button>
                                                <button onClick={() => handleReportClick(item)} className='buttonFile text-orange-400' title='Informe'>
                                                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFileAlt} />
                                                </button>
                                                <button onClick={() => handleReviewClick(item)} className='buttonClock pr-5 text-green-500' title='Revisar'>
                                                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faClock} />
                                                </button>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    );
                                })}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <ModalDetail open={openModal} onClose={handleCloseDialog} detailData={currentDetail} />
                    <div className='w-10'></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default TableListVulnerabilities;

This is my ListVulnerableDevices.jsx component:
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { useInternalVul } from "../../hooks/useInternalVul";
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const ListVulnerableDevices = ({ delegationId }) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const navegate = useNavigate();
  const componentRef = useRef(null); // Reference to the component's DOM node

  // State to store the fetched data
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false); // Visibility state
  const [ipVulData, setIpVulData] = useState(() => {
    const storedData = sessionStorage.getItem('ipVulData'); // Use sessionStorage instead of localStorage
    return storedData ? JSON.parse(storedData) : null;
  });

  // Fetch data using useInternalVul hook
  const { ipVul, isLoading, isError } = useInternalVul(delegationId);

  // IntersectionObserver to track component visibility
  useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
      ([entry]) => {
        setIsVisible(entry.isIntersecting);
      },
      { threshold: 0.5 } // Trigger when at least 50% of the component is visible
    );

    if (componentRef.current) {
      observer.observe(componentRef.current);
    }

    return () => {
      if (componentRef.current) {
        observer.unobserve(componentRef.current);
      }
    };
  }, []);

  // Store ipVul data in session storage when the component is visible
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isVisible && ipVul) {
      sessionStorage.setItem('ipVulData', JSON.stringify(ipVul)); // Use sessionStorage instead of localStorage
    }
  }, [isVisible, ipVul]);

  // Retrieve ipVul data from session storage on component mount
  useEffect(() => {
    const storedIpVulData = sessionStorage.getItem('ipVulData'); // Use sessionStorage instead of localStorage
    if (storedIpVulData) {
      setIpVulData(JSON.parse(storedIpVulData));
    }
  }, []);

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    navegate('/vulnerabilities');
  };

  if (isLoading) return <div><p>Cargando...</p></div>;
  if (isError) return <div><p>Error al cargar los datos...</p></div>;

  return (
    <div ref={componentRef}> {/* Attach ref to the component's DOM node */}
      <table className="tableDevicesVuln">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th value="PrivateIP">{t('devicesVulnerabilities.privateIP')}</th>
            <th value="Vulnerability Id">{t('devicesVulnerabilities.vulnerabilityId')}</th>
            <th value="Base Score">{t('devicesVulnerabilities.baseScore')}</th>
            <th value="Impact Score">{t('devicesVulnerabilities.impactScore')}</th>
            <th value="Severity Score">{t('devicesVulnerabilities.severityScore')}</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {ipVulData?.data?.scan_internal_ips_vuln.map((ip) => (
            ip.vulnerabilities && Object.values(ip.vulnerabilities).map((vul) => (
              <tr key={`${ip.privateip}-${vul.cve.id}`}>
                <td>{ip.privateip}</td>
                <td>{vul.cve.id}</td>
                <td>{vul.cve.metrics.cvssMetricV31[0]?.cvssData.baseScore}</td>
                <td>{vul.cve.metrics.cvssMetricV31[0]?.impactScore}</td>
                <td>{vul.cve.metrics.cvssMetricV31[0]?.cvssData.baseSeverity}</td>
              </tr>
            ))
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div className="flex w-full justify-end py-3 px-2">
        <button className='bg-cyan-700 
          hover:bg-cyan-400 
          text-white 
          text-sm 
          py-1 
          px-3'
          onClick={handleButtonClick}
        >
          {t('devicesVulnerabilities.showVulnerabilities')}
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ListVulnerableDevices;

What can be the issue?

have you checked that your data is being correctly updated in storage?
